# Does Bootstrap 3 responsive need classes for all devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When i write html, i add all classes like

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2"></div>
```

I have seen a lot of tutorials but never seen some one adding all classes to each div.

Is it a good practice to include all classes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe you have seen a lot of tutorials that don't demonstrate the "cascading" effect of the 4 Bootstrap grid sizes.

There is nothing wrong with adding multiple classes to each div, but you *only* need to write classes for the smaller of the widths. So for example, `sm` applies to 768 and greater (it means `sm` and up):

Using this...

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8"></div>
```

has the same effect as simply using..

```
<div class="col-sm-8"></div>
```

So, you'd *only* need to use all 4 `lg`,`md`,`sm` and `xs` together if you want ***different*** column sizes on desktop, laptop, tablet and phone. Here's a demo that may help to clarify: http://bootply.com/73778

Answer (score 0):

You only need to write multiple classes, if you want different looks for different sizes.

This `<div class="col-sm-8"></div>` is equal to all the rest:

```
<div class="col-md-8"></div>
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8"></div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8"></div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-8"></div>
etc..
```

You only need to write different classes, if you want different lengths per view.

eg.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6"></div>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6"></div>
```

In small devices (phones-tablets), the first column will have grid size 3, while the second will have size 9. On larger devices, both the first and second columns will have size grid size 6.

ps. keep in mind, that hardcoding all your classes in your html is not the best way. Try using a css precompiler to help you write less code!